# How can i get my iBeacon UUID and other details?

Tags: ios, swift3, ibeacon

### iBeacons Swift

Hello guys, I did buy a new **iBeacon** device from online store. But i don't get any details regarding this beacon. I did create an **iOS app** to detect nearby beacons with **uuid** but i don't know by beacon uuid. Please help how can I get uuid and other details of this device. Is there any alternative so that i can find any nearby beacons?

Comment: Apparently, you can use https://github.com/mlwelles/BeaconScanner The issue is that in iOS, beacons API are high level, and you have to know the UUID, while it's basically BLE in fact, just with some nomenclatures/rules. Android (if you have a available one that supports BLE, there should be plenty of apps) can parse itself the packets, and apparently, according to the previous GitHub macOS too, so you may find it there.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, **iOS blocks reading identifiers** of iBeacon packets unless you know the Proximity UUID up front.  If you do not know this Proximity UUID you must:

- Request it from the manufacturer
- Use a non-iOS device (Android, MacOS, Windows 10, Linux, or a dedicated Bluetooth sniffer) to read the packets it is advertising and show the Proximity UUID.

If you have an Android device, my [Beacon Scope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner) app is the quickest way to do the job.  If you have one of the other devices, various other beacon scanning programs are available.

Comment: Thank for the quick answer @davidgyoung. Is there any way i can get identifier of my iBeacon?

Comment: Uh. Yes.  That is what I answered above!

Comment: your "Locate" app link is broken. Please update it.

Comment: Updated the link to the latest app